# Strategy Pattern: Instance or Object.class?

Tags: design-patterns, instance

This will be more like an ethic question, but I'm pretty curious about it.

So, there is the Strategy Pattern, where you have a Strategy-Interface with several implementations and a bunch of methods, taking the Strategy-Interface as argument.

Let's assume the following as example:

- `Interface: SearchStrategy`
- `Class: StringSearch implements SearchStrategy`
- `Class: IntSearch implements SearchStrategy`
- `etc.`

Then there is a method like

`doSearch(String a, String b, SearchStrategy strategy)`

How would you handle the strategy object? Pass over an instance, or the class?

A: `doSearch("Hello","World", new StringSearch());`

or

B: `doSearch("Hello","World", StringSearch.class);`

So, create an instance and pass it over, or pass over the Class object and let the method create an instance. What is the better, cleaner way to it?

How about performane? Sure, on powerful servers there won't be a significant difference in performance, but what about embedded systems with only a few ressources and a slow processor?

Comment: Thinking in Java, I don see a way of StringSearch and IntSearch implementing the same interface and allowing `doSearch` to call them interchangeably.

Comment: My example might not be the best, but yet it is still just an example. At a second glance, the IntSearch is unnecessary at all ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance, of course. Passing the class will force the `doSearch()` method to instantiate, using reflection, the Strategy object. This will only work if all the classes agree on some conventions (like having a default constructor).

And it won't allow passing a strategy which has some state (like a caseSensitive flag, or a reference to another contextual object, or whatever).

I don't see how performance has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Pass over an instance. You will possibly want to pass in an instance pre-instantiated with parameters (e.g. a database connection, say), and you can't do that by passing the class itself.

I'd expect a class to be passed around if you want the code to create new instances (but then, pass a factory) or if you want to do some reflection-type mechanism, but those scenarios are few and far between.